# Going out of Bounds while Attempting to Delimit and Split a Line

Tags: java, delimiter

I have to read a file into an arraylist, then read line by line from the arrlist in order to delimit into a command (i for insert) and key (a number to insert). since Im building a skiplist. My file is composed of :

i 2173

i 2307

i 2405

i 1512

i 1783

i 60

Edit: & yes every insert command has a number next to it.

Problem is my program is suddenly going out of bounds on the following line:

int key = Integer.parseInt(letter[1]);

Why could this be happening? It successfully worked before but suddenly it goes out of bounds and when I did a print test its also skipping 1 line in between the file lines.
Code is below. Thank you.

Error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1 at SkipList.main(SkipList.java:103)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.StringBuild

public class SkipList{
    
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
      
     String line; 
     
     File file = new File("src/in10.txt");
    
     Scanner in = new Scanner(file);  
  
    //Copying File content 
     ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<>(); 
                   
    // Populates array list with text file content        
    while(in.hasNextLine()) {
     arrList.add(in.nextLine());
     }
     
     for ( int i = 0; i < arrList.size(); i++){
    
      line = arrList.get(i); 
    // System.out.println(line); 

    //Splits Line with space delimiter into String Array
    String[] letter = line.split(" ");
    
    String command = letter[0];
    int key = Integer.parseInt(letter[1]); //ERROR occurs here?
        
    }
  
  } 
                                                                                                    
}
```

Comment: *Why could this be happening?* - your data isn't in the format you expect. Do some basic debugging by displaying each line of text (before you do the split) and then display the Array length to validate the split processing.

Comment: My advice is to print out `letter.length` and each element of `letter`; probably also `line` for good measure. Maybe the line is empty? Anyway looking at the actual values could shed some light.

Comment: Are you sure **every** line will have both a command _and_ a key?  Maybe you shouldn't blindly access `letter[1]` until you're sure that `letter[0]` is a command that requires an accompanying key.

Comment: It's also quite possible that you have some garbage non-printing character in your data file. Running a debugger or at the very least, adding a println and dumping the input line to console will show you what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
// System.out.println(line); 

//Splits Line with space delimiter into String Array
String[] letter = line.split(" ");
```

You were give a couple of basic pieces of advice:

1. Display the line
2. Display the array length

So the code should be something like:

```
System.out.println("(" + line ")"); 

//Splits Line with space delimiter into String Array
String[] letter = line.split(" ");
System.out.println(letter.length);
```

The first println() will tell you if you have a blank line of something in the file.

The second println() will tell you how the split works. As suggested maybe you don't have a " " in the string but instead a non-printable character.

We can't debug the code for you because we don't have access to your text file.

Comment: Hi, thats the reason I posted the exact contents of the file. Theres nothing in it other than the commands "i" followed by a space and a number. I did display the line and array length. Its all exactly as in the file.

Comment: *thats the reason I posted the exact contents of the file* - no you didn't. Your posting shows empty lines. Your code would get a different exception if you had an empty lines. We can't tell if you really have a space between the command and the number or some other non-printable character.  *I did display the line and array length* - if you get "2" for each line then you should not have a problem. Post the output of your debugging.

Comment: Theres no empty lines in the file. If I could post it I would. Theres nothing wrong with the file. It was made by my professor and it simply contains the lines I posted above except theres no empty lines in between. I had to do that here for indentation, but thanks. Ill just delete the question and look elsewhere.

Comment: *Theres nothing wrong with the file* - I copied your data and created a file. I copied your code and tested with the file I created. It worked as expected with no Exceptions. So your code does does in fact work. This means either 1) the code you posted in the forum is not the code you are testing or 2) the data in your file is invalid.  Only you can solve your problem.